# Decltype For Class Member Function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, decltype

This code does not compile in VS2010:

```
template < typename A >
class X
{
    A& m_a;

public:
    X ( A& a ) : m_a ( a ) {}
    auto func ( int i ) -> decltype ( m_a ( i ) ) { return ( m_a ( i ) ); } // failing on this line
};

double f ( int a )
{
    return static_cast < double > ( a );
}

int main()
{
    X < decltype ( f ) > x ( f );
    std::cout << x.func(4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments.

It seems like the compiler doesn't think that m_a is in scope inside the decltype.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2010 doesn't implement `decltype` exactly as the standard specifies (to be fair, it's older than the final version of the standard). You should be able to get around this with hand-coded `declval`:

```
template < typename A >
class X
{
    A& m_a;
    static A& simulated_m_a();

public:
    X ( A& a ) : m_a ( a ) {}
    auto func ( int i ) -> decltype ( simulated_m_a()( i ) ) { return ( m_a ( i ) ); }
};
```

I've just verified on my VS2010 that it works.

Comment: In my example code, if the return type of f is not a built-in type (e.g. a std::pair), then I get warning C4172.  Why is that?

Comment: @rohitsan Where is the warning from? `f` itself, the `decltype()`, the `return` inside `func()`?

Comment: It seems to be caused by the use of the suffix return syntax in the definition of X::func.  When I replace the suffix return type with an actual return type, it compiles without the warning.